# Does anyone know what could be causing distortion on my display?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-ryzen

[image: Distorted Screen]

I have tried updating the drivers and resetting the PC but nothing seems to work. I was thinking it could be hardware but I have no idea. When I take a screenshot it comes out fine as if nothing is wrong.

It's started in the last month or so and seems to occur if I allow the PC to make the screen sleep. Anything I could try to fix it or find out more would be greatly appreciated. For now I have turned off screen sleep so that it can't do that and turned on a blank screen saver to prevent burn in.

PC Specs:

- AMD Ryzen 5 1600X
- NVidia GTX 1060 3 GB
- Corsair Vengence LPX C16 2x8GB
  2666 MHz DDR4
- Samsung 960 Evo 250 GB

Comment: (my try..) does it happens with other monitor? if yes > gfx card problem. if no > monitor problem. Either way.. seems to be a legit case for warranty claim.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to connect to anything once I unplug the displayport cable when it's happened. It's like it's connected but it's not there as my monitor detects it but then doesn't and repeatedly does that. I'll have to try connect it to my TV or something and check if/when it happens next.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this exact issue, The only fix i have foumd is to restart the computer and then disable the sleep function altogether. You can disable the sleep function in both the monitor and pc in the settings. This appears to be an issue with the monitor. My second display still works perfectly during the issue and if i unplug or turn off either screen the computer will actually freeze which is why unplugging the screen and plugging it in looked like there was no signal. The hard drive activity light stops and the lights on wifi card stop. I have no idea how this can be fixed permanantly other than disabling the sleep function. Anyone is welcome to add on from my information.